# Javascript stretch image according to a map?

Tags: javascript, image, stretch

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to stretch in image in Javascript so different parts of the image expand more quickly than others. I was thinking along the lines of an black/white map where black does not stretch at all, white stretches the most and the shades of grey in between stretch proportionately. Is this at all possible? I;m hoping to make a picture look as if its losing or gaining weight.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML5 canvas feature along Java-script to do image manipulation.

Altogh it will be processor intensive, mainly if you want to do animation, you can do it.

Some tutorial for the canvas element of HTML5 with Java-script, probably you are interested more on the *drawImage(image,x,y)* method.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

And references
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp

You could then get draw the parts you want scaled, but giving it near non noticeable artifacts effects like you want is really difficult.